# Run time HSSFWorkbook class load error

Tags: java, excel, jakarta-ee, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I'm facing the common issue of **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** during application runtime when i try to create and write a workbook using **poi 3.2 final** version (**for .xls files only**). I have created this utility as an **enterprise application project** with ejb and web modules. The workbook creation is triggered through an EJB timer which starts on load of the project to the server.

The run time fails for the class `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook`.
The library references are made as far as i'm aware. I've placed the poi 3.2 final jar in `ejb/META-INF/lib/`folder. I have also added it from the Order and Export tab of the Build path and referenced in the Java EE dependencies. For good measure, i have placed it in the **`web-inf/lib`** folder of the web project also, but to no avail.

In the same app, i am also using the Jsoup jar. After referencing it in the above stated places, **`Jsoup`** is working fine.

Curiously enough, this error does not occur when i create the same service as a web application (dynamic web project) with a regular utility timer. The workbook gets created. The jar is placed in the **`web-inf/lib`** folder.

Could someone please let me know is there any difference in the way this jar is referenced for a web project and an enterprise project?

Appreciate your patience and help..

Comment: [Apache POI 3.2 is over 7 years old now](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.2-FINAL)! Why on earth are you using such an ancient version? The list of [fixes since then is huge](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.2-FINAL)!

Comment: @Gagravarr You are absolutely right. I was initially using 3.13 poi jar (with all the ooxml jars) version which sent me on a different run time load issue.

Comment: @Gagravarr Even though i am using only the HSSF workbook related imports, on usage of the latest poi jars (anything from 3.5 to 3.13 versions), on run time loading, it looks up for the class org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichtextString. I have verified the jars also, they seem to have this class in them. Just to make it relevant atleast, i tried to use the older version which only loads HSSF packages instead of SS packages. Any ideas?

Comment: As per the [Apache POI FAQ, mixing POI jars from different versions is not supported](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C). Stop doing that! Use only 3.13 jars

Comment: @Gagravarr I am not mixing the jar versions. I meant to say, i tried using from 3.2 to 3.13 jar versions _separately_. Below is what i was using which lead to the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString class load error. poi-3.13-20150929.jar,poi-example-3.13-20150929.jar, poi-excelant-3.13-20150929.jar, poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929.jar,poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929.jar

Comment: `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString` is contained within the main POI jar, you can rename the `.jar` to `.zip` + unpack + see for yourself!

Comment: Yes, i have verified that as well. It is available. As i mentioned in my question, this works without any issues as dynamic web project. I just dont know whether running it as an enterprise application is loading the jars differently...

Comment: @Gagravarr Hi, i seem to have cleared this error. I have put the jars in ejb project which was okay for compile time, but for run time this was looking up the jars from the EAR project. So i put the jars in the META-INF/lib folder of the EAR project and referenced it. It has worked. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked when i placed the jars in the `META-INF/lib`
 folder of the EAR project as opposed to the EJB project, and referenced it in the library dependencies.